# Get Rows with Different Values or Missing from One Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have two tables which have similar structures.  Each table has an `Id` and a `FirstValue` and `SecondValue` field.  I want to use Linq-to-SQL to get each row that's in `TableOne` and not in `TableTwo` (based on `Id`) and also get each row that's in both tables, but has different values of `FirstValue` or `SecondValue`.  The SQL should be something like

```
SELECT TableOne.*
FROM TableOne
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TableTwo
       ON TableOne.Id = TableTwo.Id
WHERE TableTwo.Id IS NULL 
   OR (TableTwo.Id IS NOT NULL AND 
        (TableOne.FirstValue <> TableTwo.FirstValue OR
         TableOne.SecondValue <> TableTwo.SecondValue
        ) 
      )
```

I've tried

```
(from a in context.TableOne
 from b in context.TableTwo.Where(b =>
          a.Id == b.Id &&
         (a.FirstValue != b.FirstValue ||
          a.SecondValue != b.SecondValue)).DefaultIfEmpty()
 select a).ToList();
```

The problem in that query is that if `TableOne` and `TableTwo` have matching values, the row still gets returned, but all of the `TableTwo` values are null.  If a row has the same values in each table, I want it not to be returned at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534805(v=vs.110).aspx) to get all records from second table which correspond to entity in first table. Then simply get those records which either don't have matching records in second table, or have different values:

```
from a in context.TableOne
join b in context.TableTwo on a.Id equals b.Id into g
from b in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
where b == null || a.FirstValue != b.FirstValue || a.SecondValue != b.SecondValue
select a
```